# Did Harry and Mia actually have sex?

Tags: plot-explanation, love-actually

The movie, [*Love Actually*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Actually) from 2003 depicts Harry portrayed by [Alan Rickman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000614/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t39) as having a flirtatious relationship with his assistant, Mia portrayed by [Heike Makatsch](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0538443/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t10).

Mia is the obvious aggressor in the relationship.  Harry slowly succumbs to her advances and continues showing interest in her. The flirtation between the two quickly escalates when Harry purchases a necklace for Mia, all the while attempting to hide everything from his wife.

There is a scene in the movie that depicts Mia sitting on an unkept bed putting on the necklace that Harry had given to her.  The movie never shows the two of them actually making love.  However, it is suggested due to the state of the bed and the fact that Mia is wearing some sort of lingerie along with the necklace.

[image: Mia's necklace]

Is there any evidence that Harry and Mia actually had sex?  Was this scene just a fantasy that Mia was having?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.

[Emma Freud](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0294430/) - who was script writer/editor of the film ([*source*](http://www.closeronline.co.uk/2015/12/revealed-did-love-actuallys-harry-really-have-sex-with-mia-the-secretary)) - **and** director Richard Curtis’s wife - was discussing the film on Twitter in December 2015.

The [actual twit content is](https://twitter.com/emmafreud/status/676056685732102145):

> *emma freud ✔ @emmafreud*
>   7:10 AM - 13 Dec 2015
>    @carlotta429 **DEFINITELY had an affair**.  i begged richard just to make it a flirtation, but no.  **the whole way.**

Comment: Doesn't get more explicit than that. Good find.

Comment: She actually says later down the thread that Richard changed his mind about that. Very weird answers. She could have said anything she wanted 12 years after making the movie. Doesn't confirm anything actually.